# What is the difference between @YES/@NO and YES/NO?

Tags: objective-c, boolean, objective-c-literals

In Objective-c what is the difference between `@YES`/`@NO` and `YES`/`NO`? What types are used for each?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`@YES` is a short form of `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

&

`@NO` is a short form of `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]`

and if we write

```
if(@NO)
   some statement;
```

the above if statement will execute since the above statement will be

```
if([NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] != nil)
```

and it's not equal to `nil` so it will be `true` and thus will pass.

Whereas `YES` and `NO` are simply `BOOL's` and they are defined as-

```
#define YES             (BOOL)1

#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

`YES` & `NO` is same as `true` & `false`, `1` & `0` respectively and you can use `1` & `0` instead of `YES` & `NO`, but as far as readability is concerned `YES` & `NO` will(should) be definitely preferred.

Comment: I got your point, but I tried `BOOL status = @YES;` which worked for me without any warning or error.

Comment: @Exploring, `BOOL a = 1.0;, BOOL aa = self; BOOL aaa = @"abc";` all these statements will also work, without any complains from the compiler

Comment: They will, because an assignment to a BOOL by definition of the language checks whether the assigned item is non-zero or non-nil and assigns YES or NO.

Answer (score 19):

The difference is that by using `@` you are creating an `NSNumber` instance, thus an object. `Yes` and `No` are simply primitive Boolean values not objects.

The `@` is a literal a sort of shortcut to create an object you have it also in strings `@"something"`, dictionaries `@{"key": object}`, arrays: `@[object,...]` and numbers: `@0,@1...@345` or expressions `@(3*2)`.

Is important to understand that when you have an object such as `NSNumber` you can't do basic math operations (in obj-c) such as add or multiply, first you need to go back to the **primitive** value using methods like: -**integerValue**, **-boolValue**, **-floatValue** etc.

You probably seen it because foundation collection types works only with objects, so if you need to put a series of bools inside an `NSArray`, you must convert it into object.

Comment: This is a better answer than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: @KPM, yes I agree, it is better.

Answer (score 4):

1. @YES/@NO is type of `NSNumber`,is used when do something with Foundation object.For example

   ```
   NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [array addObject:@YES];//true
   [array addObject:YES];//Wrong
   ```
2. YES/NO is `BOOLs`

Comment: `YES` and `NO` are `BOOL`s, not `Boolean`s.